# Why can't I access a public const in c#?

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace {    

    public partial class MyClass: UserControl {

        public static const String MYCONST = "MyConstant";
```

I can't see MYCONST from anywhere even from MyClass, why ?

Comment: Do you get a compile error ? What does it say ?

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: Try to remove either of the “static” or “const” keywords.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A constant is available in a static context anyway, so remove the `static` keyword and you'll be fine.

MSDN docs:

> The static modifier is not allowed in a constant declaration.

The reason is that a constant's value has to be fully evaluated at compile time and what the compiler does is that it takes that value and *replaces* all the usages of the constant throughout the code with the constant value.

That is why it sometimes can be better to use a public readonly value instead as the compiler does *not* replace the usages with the value but instead links to the readonly variable. This is especially something to think about when using constants from another assembly since you might not update all assemblies at once and you might end up with assmblies using the old constant value.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation for [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)

> The static modifier is not allowed in a constant declaration.

Remove the static keyword from your constant and it should work.

**Edit**
Note that a `const` will be available as a class member, just like when you have `static` for non `const` variables. But for `const` the `static` is implicit and not allowed to type out.

Comment: you can't be static and constant. it's like being invisible and pink.

Comment: Try readonly instead...though that means its exposed during the static constructor. *shrugs*

Answer (score 5):

What the heck kind of compiler are you using?

In general, making constants public is not a good idea.  They behave differently from *readonly* variables, their literal value gets compiled into the IL.  Which is a problem if the const is declared in another assembly.  You could, say, ship a bug fix for an assembly that modified the const value.  The other assemblies in your product will however continue to use the old value.  The jitter won't complain about the mismatch.  Not good.

A public const is only okay if it is a 'manifest' constant.  Like Math.PI, only running the code in another universe could produce unexpected results.  A product or company name is already pretty risky.

Comment: I definitely agree. If it is going to be `public`, `protected` or `protected internal`, it should be `readonly`. Only `private` or `internal` values, or ones scoped to only a single method, should be `const`.

Answer (score 4):

It should be accessible as  `MyNamespace.MyClass.MYCONST`

Answer (score 2):

You have a compile error in your code.

When I compile your code I get this:

> The constant 'MyNamespace.MyClass.MYCONST' cannot be marked static

See the motivation for this error on Eric Lippert's blog:

- [Don't repeat yourself; consts are already static](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/10/don-t-repeat-yourself-consts-are-already-static.aspx)